# What's the name for the connector at the back of a Ethernet face plate?

Tags: ethernet, cabling

I want to know what is the correct name for the connector below as I have bought face plates but they didn't have these connectors with them so I want to purchase them.

I can't find out where to get them as I don't know what they are called or what to search for.

[image: Cat5 connector]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a standard name really

- RJ45 Module
- Snap-in CAT5E RJ45 Module
- Keystone Jack
- RJ45 Keystone module

Comment: Thanks. How do I snap this module into the face plate?

Comment: Push it in from the rear.

Comment: And is it possible to snap it back out again after?

Comment: Removal depends on specific make and model of faceplate, but generally yes. There's a latch you  can lever upwards.

Answer (score 4):

That part is called a **rj45 wall jack**